# Controlling Website Reference Image in Facebook Posting

Tags: facebook, wordpress, image, url, web

I was on Facebook, and thought to ask people to visit my website via a post. However when I pasted my website URL into the comment box, some other photo that is related to the Wordpress parent theme I'm using as a base theme showed up. How can I control what image of the site Faceboook see and relates to my website, instead of it just grabbing whatever it wants to grab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the correct Open Graph tags.

Use this debugger to get more information: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

The specific open graph tag you are looking to set is `og:image`

Example:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/image_name.png" />
```

Another important note is that Facebook caches whatever it reads from the page (name, image, description, etc.), and the only way to reset the cache is to check the page using the debug tool I mentioned.

Comment: I had no idea about this. You say this tool clears the cache for the URL in question, but is it immediate or do I have to wait for normal server propagation times?

Comment: It is immediate, and it will tell you what it is reading from the URL.  This will let you know if it has been set up correctly (Note, it won't retroactively change posts that are already on Facebook)